Question about presentation of arbitrary group $G$.
By category theory, for given group $G$, we can make $G=\langle X\mid Y\rangle$, where $X$ is generating set and $Y$ is relation.
Here is my question:

Can we choose appropriate $X$ to be $G=\langle X\mid \{e\}\rangle$, i.e., there's no relation, for any $G$? That means, to present $G$, whether choice of $X$ occurs with necessity of relations or not.


Only for free groups. Unless you completely change the meaning of the notation.

@ArturoMagidin  I understood that whether G is free is decided by given X. My question is not for given X since for arbitrary G, we can find generating set X s.t. =G and we can argue that free group F exist, which is free on X. I want to change generating set X to make G free. Does it possible?

There are mannnnnnnny many groups for which no generating set exists on which the group is free.

I think you might be confusing two different notations.  Given an existing group, we may impose additional relations, but given a generating set, there are absolutely no relations assumed.  Absolutely no finite group can be described by generators without relations, because every individual element will be of finite order, which implies you will have relations like $g^n=e$.  While you don't need to specify all the relations because some will imply others, if you don't specify any then it is impossible to get something finite.

No.
By definition, $\langle X\mid \rangle$ defines a free group.  But $\Bbb Z_2$ is not free. (Most groups aren't.)

Thanks! I think your example implies that free group is at least infinite. I missed easy point

Well, one could argue ${ e}\cong \langle \varnothing \mid \varnothing\rangle$, @user1173804.
